# Display General tab information of property window of local disks in my computer

Tags: c#, wmi, cluster-computing, drives, managed-code

I need to access the type of disk and display it in the C# code. In this image "
[Local Disk Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NDaU.jpg)" the type is local disk.
In this image "[Cluster Disk Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga4O3.jpg)" the type of disk is cluster disk.

I have used driveInfo class to get the drive details. but I'm not able to display whether the drive is cluster or local disk. d.DriveType returns whether it is a removable or fixed types. and not the required local disk or cluster type.
My code is added below:

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType);
if (d.IsReady == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
    Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
    Console.WriteLine(
        "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes", 
        d.AvailableFreeSpace);

    Console.WriteLine(
        "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes",
        d.TotalFreeSpace);

    Console.WriteLine(
        "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes ",
        d.TotalSize);
}
}
```

Is there any way to display the required info in C# code?

Thank you.